# Composing Java 8 Optionals

Tags: java, option-type

Let's suppose I have the following Optionals in my code:

```
Optional<Integer> a = Optional.of(1);
Optional<Integer> b = Optional.of(1);
Optional<Integer> c = Optional.of(1);
```

I need to implement some logic if they all (`a`,`b` and `c`) are present. How can I do that in an elegant way?

I need to do something like this (as an example):

```
...
if (a.isPresent() && b.isPresent() && c.isPresent()) {
    return a.get() + b.get() + c.get();
}
...
```

Comment: Maybe using Stream? Like:
`if (Stream.of(a,b,c).allMatch(Optional::isPresent)) {
            return Stream.of(a,b,c).map(Optional::get).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        }
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
Optional<Integer> a = Optional.of(1);
Optional<Integer> b = Optional.of(1);
Optional<Integer> c = Optional.of(1);
```

Thing is: when you declare "independent" variables like that, you have to deal with them (write code!) "independently", too.

In other words: either use some thing like `Stream.of()` or `Arrays.asList(a, b, c)` for further processing; or simply directly put these "constants" into a list/array at creation time.

Because only then you can turn to stream logic, as outlined in the comment by Luis.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a stream from all of them and perform a reduce operation:

```
Stream.of(a, b, c)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .sum();
```